# Would placing your contact form in an IFRAME help reduce spam?

Tags: iframe, spam

I haven't heard anyone suggest this technique before, so I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on it?

Would embedding an iframed version of your contact form inside a page make it more difficult for bots to locate or identify it?

Comment: The bot could still follow the url for the iframe and parse its content, finding the e-mail or whatever contact information it can understand.

Comment: I'm assuming of course that harvesting bots are created clever enough to follow any URL they can find.

Comment: See my comment below on this. Yes, a bot **could** still follow the src argument within the iframe.  But, would **all** bots attempt to do this.  My original question was, would this help reduce spam, not eliminate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, putting content in an `<iframe>` doesn't make it any harder for a crawler to find it. If anything, it means they have an even lighter weight page to target, making it easier...

Comment: What's your thought process on this? I assume as a spam bot, I'd follow links recursively until I identify a form.

Perhaps some spam bots would not include iframe src arguments as part of their spidering?   We can't assume that all bots have the same spidering algorithms, right?

Comment: If I was writing a web crawler, I'd be clever enough to know about iframes (and good old fashioned normal `<frame>`s, for that matter), given they've been about for many years now. Of course, the bot may start from a search result from a search engine, which makes the point moot if the bot understands iframes or not.

Comment: fair enough, it seems the general consensus on this is that it would have absolutely not effect.  Personally, I still feel that it would have *some* effect on reducing SPAM, even it it was only a 1% improvement.

Comment: It does have some effect, I went from 3 spams per day to none.